# MySQL : Storing business logic in table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have a table named test :

```
create table demo (name varchar(10), mark1 int, mark2 int);
```

I need the total of mark1 and mark2 for each row many times.

```
select name, (mark1 + mark2) as total from demo;
```

Which I am told is not efficient. I am not allowed to add a new total column in the table.

Can I store such business logic in Index?

I created a view

```
CREATE VIEW view_total AS SELECT name, (mark1 + mark2) as 'total' from demo;
```

I populated the demo table with:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRand(IN NumRows INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE i INT;
        SET i = 1;
        START TRANSACTION;
        WHILE i <= NumRows DO
            INSERT INTO demo VALUES (i,i+1,i+2);
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
        COMMIT;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL InsertRand(100000);
```

The execution time of

```
select * from view_total;
```

and

```
select * from demo;
```

is same, 10 ms. So I have not gained any benefit of view. I tried to create index over the view with :

```
create index demo_total_view on view_total (name, total);
```

which failed with error :

```
ERROR 1347 (HY000): 'test.view_total' is not BASE TABLE
```

Any pointer about how do I prevent the redundant action of totaling the columns?

Comment: why store this calculation as a hard value in the table?  Why not just calc the sum as needed?  Besides, management will change their mind soon enough (and you be asking how to subtract 2 numbers and store it ;-)

Comment: @tbone : Calculating a sum hundreds of time would be much costlier then reading it from somewhere... right?

Comment: not really, depends on what you have to do to store it.  For example, firing triggers on every insert & update just to maintain a sum column would be expensive.  Today, bus logic A says to sum these, tomorrow bus logic B says you need another field that multiplies them, etc. etc.  Are you planning to constantly add new fields?  Or select what you need (for whatever app, report, etc) at that time?  Much cleaner and easier that way imo.

Comment: Is 10ms causing your app to suffer performance issues?  If so, could you provide some more detail?  Remember, *premature optimisation is the root of all evil*.

Comment: The behaviour of the view performing the same as the underlying query is 100% expected. A view is nothing more than a stored query, it does not cache an execution plan, nor does it have its own statistics, so calling a view is no different at all to calling the underlying query. The optimiser must still follow the same process and the same data must be read from disk (Check EXPLAIN for each query and you should see they are exactly the same).

Comment: @eggyal Its a call center application with a gigantic database. We profiled the queries and realized that such calculations are too many. The example I provided above is just to clear the concept. The actual db has multiple instance of such calculations.

Comment: @GarethD Thanks for the "Explain" pointer. It made things a lot clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule *never* store in a table what you can calculate on exit from it. For instance, you want age, you should store date of birth. If you want the sum of two columns, you should store those two columns, nothing else.

Maintaining the data-integrity, -quality and -consistency in your database should be your paramount concern. If there is the slightest chance that a third column, which is the sum of the first two, could be out-of-sync then it is not worth doing.

As you cannot maintain the column without embedding the calculation into all code that inserts data into the table (open to being forgotten in the future and updating may break it) or firing a trigger every time you insert something (lots of additional work) you should not do this.

Your situation is a perfect use-case for views. You need to consistently calculate a column in the same way. If you let everyone calculate this as they wish then the same problems as with inserting the calculated column occur, you need to guarantee that this is always calculated the same way. The way to do this is to have a view on your table that pre-calculates the column in a standard way, that will be identical for every user.

> Calculating a sum hundreds of time would be much costlier then reading it from somewhere... right?

Not necessarily, this depends entirely on your own situation. If you have slower disks then reading the data may easily be more expensive then calculating it. Especially since it's an extremely simple calculation.

In all likelihood it will make no difference at all but if it is a major performance concern you should test both situations and decide whether the potential loss of data-quality and the additional overhead in maintaining the calculation in a table is worth the odd nano-second on extraction from the database.

Comment: That makes sense, but I am wondering why there was no performance improvement after I created a view and queried the view.

Comment: @user1263746 performance over what?  A view is simply a stored query.  Perhaps you're thinking of a materialized view (which stores the result of the query in a snapshot table)?

Comment: @tbone Oh, you are right. I think that's what I want. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: No, you won't @user. A view is simply a stored query on the table, as tbone commented. It is (almost) identical to querying the table and there won't be any performance differences.

Answer (score 3):

> Which I am told is not efficient.

By whom? Surely you should ask the person who made the statement to explain it - not us?

How is it not efficient? The *only* time it would affect performance *significantly* is where you could use an index on mark1 and/or mark2 - it won't be used for a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM demo
WHERE mark1+mark2 > 200;
```

But with indexes on both values you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM demo
WHERE mark1+mark2 > 200
AND (mark1 > (200/2) OR mark2 > (200/2));
```

The overhead of adding the 2 columns together is negligible. You can prove this yourself by measuring comparing the elapsed time of:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE mark1, mark2, name FROM demo;
```

and

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE mark1+mark2, name FROM demo;
```

(Regarding your error - if you create the index on the table then the view will automatically detect and use it).

(MariaDB supports [virtual columns](http://openlife.cc/blogs/2010/october/what-would-you-use-virtual-columns) which can be used to create a behaviour like Oracle's function-based indexes).

Comment: MariaDB supports virtual columns which actually are like Oracle's virtual columns (which in turn were like Oracle's function-based indexes).

Comment: @Symcbean, Thanks about index on table clarification.