# Set ORACLE table fields default value to a formular

Tags: oracle, expression, default

I have an oracle table like this:

```
create table tms_transaction_tbl
(
trans_id number primary key,
location_id number,
trans_date date,
resource_id number,
ts_id number,
max_value number,
booked_units number default 0,
remaining number default (select max_value-booked_units),
booked number not null ,
user_id number,
trans_time timestamp
);
```

as you can see I tried to set default value of remaining to (max_value-booked_units)

```
remainging number default (select max_value-booked_units),
```

but it gives me this error this error

```
ora-22818:subquery expression not allowed here
```

Comment: Don't think you can do that.  Look at using a trigger maybe?

Comment: if the value is always max_value-booked_units, does it need to be a column?  computing a deterministic value on the fly would best be done in for the application (via select or embedded inside a view); this avoids triggers (imo a good thing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a SELECT as a default value, it must be a constant.

If you're using Oracle 11g this is what [virtual columns](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php) are for. You can't insert into or update them but the provide a pre-calculated column in the database for you.

```
create table tms_transaction_tbl
 ( trans_id number primary key,
   location_id number,
   trans_date date,
   resource_id number,
   ts_id number,
   max_value number,
   booked_units number default 0,
   remaining number generated always as ( max_value - booked_units ) virtual,
   booked number not null ,
   user_id number,
   trans_time timestamp
   );
```

The syntax is further described in the documentation for the [CREATE TABLE statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402). If you're not using 11g you can achieve the same logic with a view on top of your table.

If you don't want to use a view or a virtual column then [I can only recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937024/mysql-storing-business-logic-in-table/14937413#14937413) that you do not store this data at all.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot refer to other columns in the DEFAULT expression

Here is the snippet from [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402)

> Restriction on Default Column Values A DEFAULT expression cannot
>   contain references to PL/SQL functions or to other columns, the
>   pseudocolumns CURRVAL, NEXTVAL, LEVEL, PRIOR, and ROWNUM, or date
>   constants that are not fully specified.